# How to use sessions to restrict access to the backend and only allow the admin to access it in flask? (Python)

Tags: python, flask

I would like to know how to restrict access to certain pages of my website using sessions. In, summery I'd like the administrator to log in through the same login form as normal users but using the credentials he entered, he'll be redirected to the backend page where he'll have full access to both front-end web pages and back-end web pages. When a user logs in, they can only view front-end web pages. I'm trying to avoid a situation where a user logs in and then changes the URL in the search bar of the web browser from 127.0.0.7/homepage to 127.0.0.7/backend and is allowed access because he's logged in.

I'm using the code below to check if the user is logged in. If they are not then they're redirected to the login page. I'm using flask framework. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

```
app.route('/backend', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def backend():
if 'userkey' in session:
    # connect to database using pymysql
    if cursor.rowcount == 0:
        return render_template('backend.html', msg="No orders found...")
    else:
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        return render_template('backend.html', orderdata=rows)

elif 'userkey' not in session:
    return redirect('/login')
else:
    return redirect('/login')
```

Comment: I can't directly answer your question about how to accomplish this with your session, but it can be achieved fairly easily using a login manager such as [Flask-Login](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Indeed one does not typically implement this themselves but uses a module.

Comment: I'll look into that

Comment: why have I been barred from asking questions?

Answer (score 1):

You must already be setting session['userkey'] in your login view once the user has authenticated, you just need to add the additional information about the users admin status to get this working. It would also be much easier if you moved all of the `if 'userkey' in session` checks outside of your view function into a decorator so that it can easily be reused to protect all of your view functions. This pattern is shown in the flask documentation under the heading 'Login Required Decorator' http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/viewdecorators/.

In your login function you should query your database for the users admin status at the same time as retrieving the userkey and hashed password. Then simply set session["admin"] = True if the user is an admin or don't set this at all if they are not an admin.

The following code would then work for the decorator.

```
from functools import wraps
from flask import session

def login_required(status=None):
    def login_decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if 'userkey' in session and (status is None or status in session):
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return redirect("/login")
        return wrapper
    return login_decorator
```

This decorator should then be applied to protect all of your view functions. It will then be executed prior to each view function either allowing the view to proceed if all the conditions are met or redirecting the user back to the login page if not. It takes an optional single argument status which in your case should be 'admin' for all of the back end views and should not be supplied for the front end views that do not require admin privileges. The functools.wraps decorator inside the function is just there to update the metadata of the wrapped function so that attributes like `function.__name__` behave as expected. The 'userkey' in session check is the same as in your original code but we additionally check if a status was supplied and if so if it is also stored in the session. In your case the only value of status would be 'admin' but this pattern could easily be expanded to allow other groups that would each have access to different parts of the website.

Give that all the user checks are carried out in the decorator your backend view function can be simplified to

```
@app.route('/backend', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required("admin")
def backend():
    # connect to database using pymysql
    if cursor.rowcount == 0:
        return render_template('backend.html', msg="No orders found...")
    else:
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
    return render_template('backend.html', orderdata=rows)
```

The same decorator can be used to protect all of your front end view functions, just omit the "admin" argument.

```
@app.route('/frontend', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required()
def frontend():
    # .....
```

Comment: could you break down what @wraps decorator does

Comment: as well as the required in session bit